# Can't see the extra login buttons for external identity providers

Tags: authentication, federated-authentication, login

Basically, that's the first time I'm playing with external identity providers in a federated authentication setup (Sitecore 9.1).

I can't say why but **even after configuring everything** I need following [this document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html) from Sitecore I still can't see an extra button on this page.

What could I be missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into following series for 9.1 https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2019/03/14/sitecore-identity-part-3-connecting-to-external-identity-provider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore Federated Authentication provides a new login page endpoint that allows Sitecore to redirect users directly to an external identity provider login page (without showing the login page in Sitecore) and then wait until the user clicks on the corresponding button.

If you try to access the /sitecore/login page when SI is enabled, you are redirected to the login page specified for the shell site.

Stop identity server website and then refresh this page, you will see two login buttons.